# Using FuzzyJess: fuzzy-match is not defined

Tags: eclipse, fuzzy, jess

I have downloaded an installed Jess plugin for eclipse and FuzzyJ Toolkit with it. Now I am trying to run the following simple code:

```
(import nrc.fuzzy.*)

(bind ?temperature (new FuzzyVariable "temperature" 0 100 "°C"))
(bind ?pressure (new FuzzyVariable "pressure" 0.1 50 "MPa"))

(?temperature addTerm "cold" (new RightLinearFuzzySet 6 20))
(?temperature addTerm "warm" (new TrapezoidFuzzySet 15 20 25 30))
(?temperature addTerm "hot"  (new LeftLinearFuzzySet 25 50))

(?pressure addTerm "low"    (new RightLinearFuzzySet 0.9 5))
(?pressure addTerm "medium" (new TrapezoidFuzzySet 2 8 14 28))
(?pressure addTerm "high"  (new LeftLinearFuzzySet 22 50))

(deffunction about (?number ?fuzzyVariable)
    (bind ?delta (- (?fuzzyVariable getMaxUOD) (?fuzzyVariable getMinUOD)))
    (new FuzzyValue ?fuzzyVariable 
        (new TriangleFuzzySet 
            (- ?number (* ?delta 0.01))
        ?number   
            (+ ?number (* ?delta 0.01)) 
        )
    )
)

; (printout t ((about 34 ?temperature) plotFuzzyValue "*"))

(assert (Temperature (about 43 ?temperature)))

(defrule trivial-rule
    (Temperature ?t & :(fuzzy-match ?t "hot"))
    =>
    (assert (Pressure (new FuzzyValue ?pressure "low")))    
)

(defrule printing
    (Pressure ?p)
    =>
    (printout t (?p plotFuzzyValue "*"))    
)


(run)
```

However when I run the code, I only get an exception saying that function fuzzy-match is not defined. I already changed the main class to FuzzyMain. I also tried to run FuzzyConsole and load the code from there, as well as trying to add FuzzyFunctions to the engine using addPackage, but in any case I still get that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although *Jess in Action* unfortunately doesn't tell you this, you have to explicitly load the fuzzy functions, even when launching with `FuzzyMain`. Add the following line near the top of your Jess code and it will work as desired:

```
(load-package nrc.fuzzy.jess.FuzzyFunctions)
```